# Expected initializer before '.' token c++

Tags: c++, class, struct, token

I'm getting this error at the dot, before "codigo", on 
const EstruturaApresentacao TUApresentacao::ESTRUTURA_VALIDA.codigo = "0020";

I'm stuck for a while at this problem.
Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

entidades.h

```
#include <string>

typedef struct Estrutura_Apresentacao {
    string codigo;
    string data;
    string horario;
    string preco;
    string sala;
    string disponibilidade;
}EstruturaApresentacao;
```

teste.h

```
#include "entidades.h"
using namespace std;

class TUApresentacao {
 private:

    void monta();
    void desmonta();
    void testarCenarioSucesso();

    static const EstruturaApresentacao ESTRUTURA_VALIDA;

    Apresentacao *pApresentacao;

  public:

    void run();
};
```

testes.cpp

```
#include "testes.h"
#include <iostream>

const EstruturaApresentacao TUApresentacao::ESTRUTURA_VALIDA.codigo = "0020";
const EstruturaApresentacao TUApresentacao::ESTRUTURA_VALIDA.data = "18/04/19";
const EstruturaApresentacao TUApresentacao::ESTRUTURA_VALIDA.horario = "10:30";
const EstruturaApresentacao TUApresentacao::ESTRUTURA_VALIDA.preco = "212,15";
const EstruturaApresentacao TUApresentacao::ESTRUTURA_VALIDA.sala = "8";
const EstruturaApresentacao TUApresentacao::ESTRUTURA_VALIDA.disponibilidade = "102";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't initialize individual members like that. You could initialize the whole structure:

```
const EstruturaApresentacao TUApresentacao::ESTRUTURA_VALIDA = {
  "0020",
  "18/04/19",
  "10:30",
  "212,15",
  "8",
  "102"
};
```